# How can I pass delegates to a function for generic delegates?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have a function to return relevant text from various windows controls.
I was hoping to be able to create something a little more elegant, and less static.
Here's code that functions the way I want it to:

```
    public string returnText(Control controller)
    {
        string bob = controller.GetType().Name.ToString();
        if (bob == "TextBox")
            return ((TextBox)controller).Text;
        else if (bob == "ComboBox")
            return ((ComboBox)controller).SelectedValue.ToString();
        else
            return "Invalid Object";
    }
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

Calling code:

```
        TextBoxValue del = x => x.Text;
        ComboBoxValue com = x => x.SelectedValue.ToString();
        bob.returnText2(this.cboUnitType, com);
        bob.returnText2(this.txtCurbAdj, del);
```

Function:

```
    public string returnText2<T>(T controller, Func<T, string> lambda )
    {
        return lambda(controller);
    }
```

I'm guessing I'm doing the generic side of things wrong, but I haven't been able to figure out the right way to do it.
Or maybe I'm completely out to lunch here.

Comment: Is your return value always a property of your control and return always a string ? if yes have you taken a look at reflection ?

Comment: For this particular function, yes, the return type will always be a string.  I haven't taken a look at reflection, but I'll check the docs.  Was there anything in particular that you think it could be used for here?

Comment: ok, your code looks fine, so, what is your question? what is your problem?

Comment: @VadimMartynov I'm running into an error which states that I cannot convert ComboBoxValue to System.Func<Control, string>  .  Which I assume means I've done something not quite kosher.

Comment: @Rolan i did put an answer covering an example with reflection. Obviously i covered an example with `String` type but you can make different ones handling other types

Comment: @Franck Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you have an object that is supposed to expose a property called `Text` that returns a `string`. This sounds like an interface to me. One way of going about this would be to create such interface (e.g. `IControlWithText`), then create your own derived `TextBox` and `ComboBox` classes that implement it, then use those instead and pass them around using the interface type. This obviously may be overkill, depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a cleaner (and clearer) version of your original code.  It doesn't use any reflection, generics or ToString calls.  Instead, it uses a *pattern matching* switch statement:

```
public static string ReturnText(Control control)
{
    switch (control)
    {
        case TextBox tb:
            return tb.Text;
        case ComboBox cb:
            return cb.SelectedText;
        //etc.
        default: return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

By the way, your use of the name *`controller`* for a variable of type `Control` is misleading; controller has real meaning in other contexts.

An alternative would be to create a `Dictionary<Type, Func<Control, string>>` where an entry would look like `{typeof(Textbox), c=>((TextBox)c).Text}`, but I think that would be a lot less clear than just using a switch like I've shown.

**One other thing:** You could make this function an *extension method* on the `Control` type (by putting it in a static class and putting the keyword `this` before `Control` in the parameter list).  I'd probably rename it `GetTextValue`.  At that point, you could just say `var textValue = anyControl.GetTextValue();` for any control on your page.  Unfortunately, there isn't an `extension property` yet in C#

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean with regard to the issue of clarity.  I was thinking it would be an easy way to pass generic functions which could be executed on some fields (I'm doing some custom validation stuff), but it doesn't look like that's a simple thing to do.  It looks like your approach will work for what I need to do, though. Thanks.

Comment: @Rolan: As someone who reviews *way* too much code in a day, don't underestimate the value of _clarity_!

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection is pretty easy. What you do is use the type of the class to retrieve their properties. Then you request the value of that property on an object and you got the value.

here a quick simple reflection. What it does is get the type of the object, request the property named `SelectedValue` then query the `combobox` object to retrieve the value and finally convert as string.

```
var combobox = this.cboUnitType;
var value = combobox.GetType().GetProperty("SelectedValue").GetValue(combobox ).ToString();
```

Here the same thing made into a function and quite generic plus has possible error handling

```
private string GetValue(object obj, string property)
{
    var value = "";

    try
    {
        value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(obj).ToString();
    }
    catch { }

    return value;
}
```